# How can I smooth a half cylinder without losing sides?

Tags: modeling

I've tried smooth shading in addition to modifiers like edge split and subdivision surface but the edges become so round that the edges are not longer closed.

[image: no smooth]
[image: Shade smooth]
[image: edge split and subdivision surface]

Thanks for the help!

Comment: use Shade Smooth + Auto-Smooth? but it will just smooth between the faces, it won't add faces, to add faces, use Subdivisions Surface. As it will make the edges round, bevel the edges

Comment: Your third link is just an upload link.

Comment: Properties Editor > Data > Normals > Auto Smooth ... please next time include screens into your question ... there is an icon for that :)

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIFs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: Properties Editor > Data > Normals > Auto Smooth << I've tried this but the edge of the faces look sharp and if I increase the angle all the sides disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you use a default cylinder with 32 vertices on a side, but lower than standard depth, then cut it in half, like so:

[image]

All I've done after cutting the cylinder in half and adding a face in the hole, was right-clicking the object -> *Shade Smooth* then go to Object *Data Properties > Normals > Auto Smooth* and left the angle at default 30°.

[image]

If you want to smooth the edges, you need to add geometry, e.g. automatically with subdivision surface, but then you need either to use <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> creases to not round particular edges...

[image]

...or add <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> holding edge loops:

[image]

which gives you more control where exactly to position them if you want smooth edges - but in this case I'd recommend <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> Bevel for that:

[image]

Or just use Bevel modifier before subdivision modifier.

Comment: sort of! But as you can see the half circle edge is still a bit sharp. You can see the geometry of the multiple faces in the edge. I would like to achieve a rounded smooth edge as in the third image in my post.

Answer (score 0):

For hard (not smooth) edges, u can still use Subdivision Modifier, but don't apply it yet!

First add some loopcuts where u want the hard edges, and move the loopcuts as near as possible to the edges u want to be hard
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDww5.png)

Comment: Thanks! This definitely helped but It created a weird indentation in the base of the figure. How can I remove this edge or merge the 2 faces? I tried dissolve edge but it distorts the figure: https://ibb.co/L6Fqdzt

Comment: For merging faces, select a vertex of each of the faces u wanna join, press Alt+M, then click on At Center... But if you're using Mirror Modifier, then enable "clipping", and move them together.